# Connecting with Facebook / Twitter on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, authentication, twitter

I've got a client who wants an app which can log in via email, and also connect with Facebook or Twitter. So the initial page will look something like this app:

[image]

The client's API is already built, and once the app is connected to a user's Facebook or Twitter account, the client's API requires this stuff to register an account:

- id
- access token
- token secret (Twitter only)

There seems to be half a dozen libraries and pods to dealing with connecting with Facebook and Twitter.  It's a little confusing as to which of all the routes to take. Is there a solution which is both simple and dependable?